# d3heatmap returns selection to server

Tags: r, shiny, d3heatmap

I am incorporating d3heatmap in a shiny app. Is there any way to return the id of selected rows/columns or the zoomed in area selected by the user to the server? This is just like the "hover" or "brush" options in "plotOutput". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, d3heatmap package currently does not have that functionality built in. It is planned to be included for the next revision expected to be released in 2017.